# Convertir Archivos PDF en HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html

Tengo el siguiente archivo html utilizando js para poder mostrar todo el contenido de un archivo pdf en html, pero al abrir el archivo no se muestra nada, este es el código en html el cual contiene en la URL del documento en pdf.

````
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        pdfjsLib.getDocument('DIAP/Curso1/Curso1_La_persona_fundamento.pdf').then(doc => {console.log("This file has" + doc._pdfInfo.numPages + "pages"); 

                doc.getPage(1).then(page => {
                    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
                    var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
                    var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                    myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
                    myCanvas.height = viewport.height;

                    page.render({
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    });

                });

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>```



Estos son los Errores:
Uncaught TypeError: pdfjsLib.getDocument(...).then is not a function
    at index.html:10



  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/SergioGarz%C3%B3n/DIAP/Curso1/DIAP/Curso1/Curso1_La_persona_fundamento.pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
````

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer es un problema de la bibloteca, https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11960, sin embargo puedes solucionarlo utilizando las promesas

```
const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument('file-sample.pdf');
loadingTask.promise.then(doc => {.... }
```

También hay que considerar que el acceso de los archivos es de tipo CROS, por lo que no puedes usar URL tipo file://, **solo puedes usar archivos que sea accesibles por http:// o https://**, para solucionar eso, debes **tener un servidor web y poder acceder a tus archivos .pdf desde dicho servidor**...

Te dejo un ejemplo de como usarlo

```js
const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument('https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf'); //aqui puedes usar tu servidor http://localhost/site/samplefile.pdf
    loadingTask.promise.then(doc => {
        
        doc.getPage(1).then(page => {
            
            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
            var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            };
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Aparecen los siguientes errores:                                                                                                                        Uncaught TypeError: pdfjsLib.getDocument(...).then is not a function at (index):11                             Failed to load resource: the server /DIAP/Curso1/DIAP/Curso1/Curso1_La_persona_fundamento.pdf:1 responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                                                                               Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Comment: @Sergio estás usando el `const loadingTask = ..` y ejecutando la promesa `loadingTask.promise... ` ??... el error del documento aparece porque la ruta que estás usando no existe o no se encuentra.. prueba consultar directamente tu ruta en el navegador usando http://

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado usar jQuery junto con pdfjs, algunas librerías necesitan jquery como librería complementaria, prueba a agregarla esto `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>` en el head antes de pdfjs